# pg_basebackup: could not get WAL end position from server

Tags: backup, postgresql, replication

I want to create a Base Backup with the pg_basebackup tool of postgres 9.1. After some seconds I receive:

``pg_basebackup: could not get WAL end position from server`

What can be the reason for this error message?

Comment: `pg_basebackup`is relatively new (just came into existence in January) and not particularly well-documented - you may get a faster answer asking on the Postgres mailing lists (and when you get an answer, post it here for free upvotes :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem was that there were files in the data directory not owned by the postgres user.

Comment: how did you figure this out dude? This post saved me a ton of headaches but the error message gave no clue to the issue